# Error while installing ggbiplot - object 'digest_impl' not found

Tags: r, github, devtools, ggbiplot

When installing ggbiplot I get the following error:

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")

Downloading GitHub repo vqv/ggbiplot@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/vqv/ggbiplot/zipball/master
Installing ggbiplot
Error in `_digest`(c(list(repos, type), lapply(`_additional`, function(x) eval(x[[2L]],  : 
  object 'digest_impl' not found
```

Obviously it is missing something. Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Seconded. On my system, I suspect it got something to do with Rtools.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @LucasSoares: Did you fix the problem?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I did many things, I don't really remember which one solved the issue. Updated R, Updated RStudio, removed non-standard characters from the R path, put Rtools on the system PATH variable, changed folder permissions such that my user could write on the folder R saves packages. I suspect the two last steps were the *real* solution.

Comment: @LucasSoares: I figured it out. I updated R from 3.1.x to 3.2.4, and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

you could try to install package digest first, via

```
install.packages("digest")
```